# a recursive instantiating of objects?

Tags: java

```
public class ran {

    ran obj1 = new ran();//will this create a recursive instantiating of objects??
    public String s = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ran obj2 = new ran();
        obj2.s = "main";
        obj2.obj1.s = "secondary";
        System.out.println(obj2.obj1.s);

    }

}
```

> the above code gives a stack overflow error..so what is exactly
> happening here? the obj2 is instantiated ,with it is instantiated
> obj1,and obj1 then again instantiates another object of ran class and
> a chain is formed??
>
> if so then is there a workaround without making obj1 as static ?

### on special behest of buddy hovercraft..

edit to question=i was trying to replicate a self referential structure ,like the one used in c/c++ in linked lists

Comment: When you find yourself in situation like this, you should leave everything and reconsider your design before someone dies.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this recursively as this is a bad design and if done like this will always lead to a stackoverflow? Your question is a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you need to tell us what your goal is, not how you're trying to solve it, because your current approach is way off base.

Comment: fresh off c++ and pointers...so tried a similar structure here...

Comment: don't want to achieve anything.just poking around with java.is it such a bad thing to do(the poking ,not the asking of this question) :P

Comment: `"don't want to achieve anything.just poking around with java"` -- OK, then you've learned how to recursively create objects causing a stackoverflow. Mission accomplished, now on to learning some useful things.

Comment: Regardless of your goal, any recursion will have problems if you don't give it a decent stop condition. Where is your stop condition? Answer: there is none.

Comment: u see ..i dont intend recursion to happen.i dint start writing this code to get a recursive crap..it just so happened and then boom..i'm here

Comment: Then don't use recursion. But again, **what is your goal with this code**? If you tell us what you're trying to achieve, we can help better. If not, then all we can do is say, "yep, you've sure got a problem".

Comment: i was trying to replicate a self referential structure ,like the one used in c/c++ in linked lists

Comment: Then Howard Guo has your solution, and you should accept his answer. Give your Ran class a Ran variable and pass a reference to the next Ran variable link via a setter method. But don't use infinite recursion without a good reason, and without a good stopping condition.

Comment: Note that your last comment should be part of your original question since it is critical information that describes the problem. You can edit your question and place it in there, and I suggest you do that so that future visitors to this site will understand what's going on without having to look at comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that you are trying to build a list-alike structure.

The usual pattern is:

```
class Ran {
    Ran obj1 = null;
    Ran() { initializer } }
    void setObj1(Ran obj1) { this.obj1 = obj1; }
}
```

If not, then you should consider constructing recursive object's data in Ran class, instead of constructing recursive objects.

Comment: oh c'mon i an mot playing hide and seek with you guys here

Comment: i tried the same thing by putting the obj1 instantiation inside main,but then i had to make it static...when i put obj1's instantiation inside the constructor of ran..again recursion!

Comment: Please move main out of Ran, give Ran its own class