# Multithreaded Programming In Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning the multithreading concept in Java and came across a program that creates a new thread by implementing the runnable class. Here is a part of the code where I have my doubts:

```
class Demo implements Runnable
{
    Thread t;
    Demo()
    {
        t=new Thread(this,"child_thread1");
        System.out.println("Thread Info:"+t);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Now, could anyone please explain to me what is the use of `this`? Instead of passing `this` I tried passing an object of the `Demo` class. It turned out that `child_thread1` didn't even run!

Comment: `this` is a reference to the current instance, which is `Runnable`, which a Thread can call

Comment: you(thread code) are already inside the object of `Demo` class that can be accessed by `this`.

Comment: The two comments above are better than both answers below :)

Comment: If you pass a new instance of `Demo` instead of `this`, it will likely instantiate an infinite number of threads recursively before they are started...

Comment: Wow, can't say I've ever encountered the self-running thread pattern before, and I don't think I like it.  Seemed fishy to me at a glance, there is already discussion here on why that is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623285/why-not-to-start-a-thread-in-the-constructor-how-to-terminate  If you are just learning threaded programming for the first time you should definitely be starting with more basic and traditional constructs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: if u pass the object of demo , then u will have a recursion and stack overflow..a similar question that i asked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205321/a-recursive-instantiating-of-objects

Comment: Passing this to a thread in the constructor is highly discouraged! There might happen very strange things like `run` gets called before the object construction has been finished.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "this" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

"[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.String))":-

> this keyword can be used to refer current class instance variable.
>
> this() can be used to invoke current class constructor.
>
> this keyword can be used to invoke current class method (implicitly).
>
> this can be passed as an argument in the method call.
>
> this can be passed as argument in the constructor call.
>
> this keyword can also be used to return the current class instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here 'this' means a Object of a Thread/Runnable . Since  Demo Class is inherited Runnable Interface Demo class can be considered as a thread. so parsing key word '    this' which refers to  the current object , when we call '    t.start()' it execute run() method in a new thread. And of course you can parse new Demo Object as well but create that object with a different constructor because otherwise when we create Demo object it will call constructor in a loop.Here is an Example

```
public class Demo implements Runnable{
Thread t1,t2;
public Demo(){
    //Create Child 1 with First constructor
    t1=new Thread(new Demo(true),"Child-1");
    System.out.println("Thread Info:"+t1);
    t1.start();
    //Create Child 2 with Second constructor
    t2=new Thread(new Demo(1),"Child-2");
    System.out.println("Thread Info:"+t2);
    t2.start();
}
public Demo(boolean b){
    t1=new Thread();
    t2=new Thread();
}
public Demo(int i){
    t1=new Thread("Constructor 2"){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Internal Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    };
    t1.start();
}
@Override
public void run() {
    //Work goes Here/
    System.out.println("Thread Works :"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
/**/

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Default Constructor
    Demo demo=new Demo();
}
```

}

Here When we call Second constructor , 'Constructor-2' named thread is invoked through 'Child-2' Thread.